# Flitch plate vs LVL for sistering an engineered beam

Tags: structural

here's the quick skinny: I'm looking to reduce the deflection on a 13' beam before doing tile work on the above floor. It's a 5" wide parallam and it's deflecting at least 1/4". it's bearing on triple 2x6 on each end.

Option 1: sister LVL glue and screw. either a single ply LVL to one side, or one ply on either side. I can get a bit of bearing on each end, they're lighter and easy to source. From what i'm reading, many have a wax coating which could make glue pretty useless

Option 2: 1/4-3/8" flitch plate. the advantage here is that there's about 1/2" available on one side of the current bearing for this to bear at least 3" on both ends. downside: heavy and maybe harder to source. I wouldn't want to through bolt, but i see there's some lag type screws rated for this type of application.

I've got some current opinions which lean towards LVL, but i'm feeling like a bit of overkill.

Comment: I would rather have overkill than having my grout and or tiles popping off the floor. 1/4” is a large deflection.

Comment: Any reason you can't replace the existing beam entirely? New LVL isn't going to deflect perceptibly (if sized properly), so why bother with the hassle of merging the two?

Comment: I did a dual-plate flitch beam at my previous home so I could remove a post. You'd want 3/8" material for a single-side, and you'd want to use enough fasteners so it can't buckle between them. A pair every 24" or so should do.

Comment: That said, your question comes down to opinion (and therefore is little more than a popularity vote). As such, it's [off topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).